# Calculating durability - how many cycles till failure?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to find any kind of source on how to calculate durability of any element that is used in cycles.

For example let's say we have such a sliding element that is working in cycles of 1s under the coaxial force of 100N, while the load is one-sided pulsating - I just made up these numbers for the sake of the example:
[image]

Now knowing the time of one cycle and and the force, how can I calculate how many cycles are required till a failure?
On google I can only find Palgrem-Miner law for ball bearings.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Not knowing what you have searched for, have you tried searches for metal fatigue?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I was typing wrong phrases while looking for it'

Comment: Put it in a cyclic testing machine - or check out mtbf…

Comment: If the stress is below the endurance limit for steel , it has no life limit. All other metals will have a fatigue life ( stress vs cycles). The catch is you need to know the stress, including stress concentrations like notches and changes in crossection.